# Борьба со статическими переменными или очередная попытка выстрелить себе в ногу?

Tags: c++, c

Сложилась такая ситуация, для своего C++ приложения я переделал проект консольного приложения написанного на языке Си в статическую библиотеку и все прекрасно работает, но там густо используют static и extern переменные и функции, поэтому если я обращусь к методам библиотеки дважды за одну сессию приложения (раньше не было предусмотрено что к int main() будет несколько обращений в 1 потоке=) ), то все статические переменные, естественно, уже объявлены и имеют значения, что вызывает некорректную работу. Ищу способ избавиться от такого поведения. 
Сторонний код достаточно обширный и исправлять в нем все моменты будет длительной и кропотливой работой. Предполагаю что в данном случае мне поможет обращение к методам библиотеки в новом потоке, но в гугле нашел очень мало упоминай как это сделать и что это, по факту, очень опасный говнокод. Возможно мне поможет FreeLibrary? Или есть практики еще проще?

Comment: напишите функцию, которая "обнулит" переменные.

Comment: @KoVadim одних только ключевых слов static в проекте больше полутора тысяч=)

Comment: я знаю один такой проект. Там где то такое же кол-во static и те же проблемы. Но глаза боятся, а пальцы клацают!

Comment: Попробуйте предоставить нам [mcve], т.е. например на базе единственной `static` переменной. Это существенно упростит понимание Вашей проблемы.

Comment: @alexolut проблема именно в том, что их больше полутора тысяч :D

Comment: @alexolut ну банальнj static bool initialized = false; после первого захода становиться true, что уже не то поведение которого я ожидаю.

Comment: @KoVadim спаcибо, это мотивирует=) если в ближайшее время не будет вариантов лучше я прислушаюсь к вашему мнению и мнению Anton Shchyrov, но надеюсь будут еще решения

Comment: Если состояние переменной должно начинаться каждый раз с чистого листа, то это явно не должна быть `static` переменная. Тут просто нужны отдельные экземпляры классов. Но вообще, я не очень понимаю, почему `initialized == true` это плохо, если действительно всё что надо инициализировано. Пользуйся на здоровье, как говорится, в таком случае.

Comment: @D-side я понял, что их много, но для лучшего понимания проблемы достаточно рассмотреть на примере одной переменной. Этого и требует первое слово в `[mcve]`.

Comment: @alexolut я полностью с вами согласен, и мне непонятно почему в том коде так много static переменных, возможно я не вижу всей картины, так как видел ее автор кода, факт что проблема есть. (если флаг 'initialized' будет поднят, то, к примеру, программа уже не обратит внимание на новые параметры на входе в функцию)

Comment: @Alexei   Вопрос следует закрыть, так как никакой конкретики нет.

Comment: Ключевая фраза **я переделал проект консольного приложения написанного на языке Си в статическую библиотеку** . Автор переделывает код . И так как логика работы программы отличается от логики работы библиотеки особено в плане работы с переемеными. Автору нужно полностью переделать логику работы под библиотеку.

Answer (score 4):

Поверьте, лучше не полениться и исправить сейчас - убрать все глобальные переменные. Да кропотливо, но правильно.

Пара LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary заставит эту библиотеку работать сейчас, но о многопоточной работе забудьте вообще

Answer (score 2):

Если это сторонняя библиотека, тем более большая, делать в ней структурное преобразование дело опасное.

Я вижу два варианта решения:

**Первый вариант**:

1. Создайте структуру, содержащую поля под все статические переменные библиотеки.
2. Добавьте методы (принимающие на вход такую структуру):

   а. "обнуление статических переменных" (последовательное выставление
   им первоначальных значений)

   б. "сохранить состояние статических
   переменных" (полное копирование значений стат. переменных в
   структуру)

   в. "восстановление статических переменных из структуры"
   (полное копирование значений из структуры в стат. переменные)
3. В родительском приложении, когда нужно, Вы можете теперь сохранять состояние, обнулять и управлять им.

Плюсы: нет правок в логике, т.к. не связано с основной логикой приложения. Полное управление контекстом на стороне родителя.

Минусы: достаточно геморройно для ~1500 статических переменных.

**Второй вариант**:

1. Создайте обертку над статической библиотекой, которая принимает набор команд любыми средствами межпроцессного взаимодействия, и результат своей работы возвращает этими же средствами. И управляется этими же средствами.
   Это вряд ли очень трудоемко, по-сути, достаточно сделать бесконечный луп с прослушиванием канала (zeromq даёт прекрасные средства для сетевого взаимодействия, и тоже бустовая лицензия), понимая команды закончить работу, выполнить такую-то функцию, ждать команду всё остальное время.
2. В родительском проекте породите столько таких подпроцессов, сколько нужно. Они будут висеть, в ожидании команды о смерти, или команды о выполнении чего-либо. У каждого процесса будет свой набор состояний статических переменных.

Мне второй вариант нравится больше, но решать Вам.